# How to conditionally copy fields from one collection and add them to another in MongoDB with PyMongo?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, pymongo

I've got two collections in MongoDB called collection_A and collection_B.

Essentially, I want to copy over a field from collection B given a condition in collection A but I'm not quite sure how to do this via PyMongo.

**Collection Schemas**:

collection_A

```
{
"ID": ObjectId(1234567),
"match": "yes"
}
```

collection_B

```
{
"B_ID": 1234567,
"add_field": "field_name"
}
```

In psuedocode, what I aim to do is:

```
if collection_A match = "yes":
    loop through records
    if collection_A ID = collection_B B_ID:
        add "add_field": "field_name" field to collection_A
```

What I have so far:

```
values = collection_A.find({"match": "yes})
for doc in values:
    TO-DO
```

I've looked around a lot on how to do this via PyMongo but was unable to find much. If anyone can help me with this problem, or direct me to useful links, that'd be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example copies all the required field from B to A that matches on ID. The comments explain each step.

```
for a_record in db.collection_A.find({'match': 'yes'}):  # Loop through collection A based on filter
    b_record = db.collection_B.find_one({'B_ID': a_record.get('ID')}, {'_id': 0, 'add_field': 1})  # Lookup corresponding record in Collection B
    if b_record is not None:  # B record will be None if no match
        db.collection_A.update_one({'_id': a_record['_id']}, {'$set': b_record})  # Update A with the value from B
    else:
        db.collection_A.update_one({'_id': a_record['_id']}, {'$set': {'add_field': None}})
```

Worked example with data:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
  
db.collection_A.insert_one({
    "ID": 1234567,
    "match": "yes"
})

db.collection_B.insert_one({
    "B_ID": 1234567,
    "add_field": "field_name"
})

for a_record in db.collection_A.find({'match': 'yes'}):  # Loop through collection A based on filter
    b_record = db.collection_B.find_one({'B_ID': a_record.get('ID')}, {'_id': 0, 'add_field': 1})  # Lookup corresponding record in Collection B
    if b_record is not None:  # B record will be None if no match
        db.collection_A.update_one({'_id': a_record['_id']}, {'$set': b_record})  # Update A with the value from B


print(list(db.collection_A.find({})))
```

prints:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5fc555172bc0555f17ccb918'), 'ID': 1234567, 'match': 'yes', 'add_field': 'field_name'}]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much and this logic makes sense too. By the way, how can I rename the `add_field` field to something else (preferably integrated within this code)?

Comment: Also if you can possibly update the logic to have `NaN` as the `add_field` value for records that don't have a match, that'd be helpful as well

Comment: To add extra fields just add them to the projection, e.g. `a_record.get('ID')}, {'_id': 0, 'add_field': 1, 'another_field': 1})`

Comment: If there's not match just add an else to the if and add whatever you like.

Comment: Hm that's what I was thinking but what be the `$set` value in that case instead of `b_record`?

Comment: Ok I edited the top section of the answer to give an example.

Comment: I used None (null) rather than NaN as NaN doesn't mean anything in MongoDB or pymongo.

Comment: Thank you, and this would keep the other fields intact while just adding an additional `None` field, correct?

Comment: Yes the `$set` operator only affects the fields being set.